# Windows 10 Pivot control Carousel and Stationary

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, user-interface

I know this question has been asked before but I don't think that [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn997788.aspx) Microsoft article  has ever been mentioned? It seems to suggest there may be a way to force the pivot into stationary mode. Does anyone know how this works? I am looking for something similar to 6tag by Rudy Huyn or the People and Calls app in Windows 10 Mobile.

Any help or information is much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: I think, your given link has been expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that the only way I have found to do this is to make that there are no more than 4 items in the Pivot view. If there are more than 4 the control goes into the "Carousel" mode.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/pivot) of `Pivot`:

> Pivots are **stationary** when all pivot headers **fit within the allowed space**.
>
> Pivots are **carousel** when all pivot headers **don't fit within the allowed space**.

So, you should take care about the "sum of width" of all `PivotHeaders` along with the `ActualWidth` of `PivotSection`. For more details, you can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/pivot).